# Squid3 block website during work hours

Tags: linux, proxy, debian, squid

I'm trying to black facebook (and other websites) during work hours with our local squid3 proxy server.
I use below cron.tab with blockedsites.txt file configured in squid3.conf as acl deny file:

```
30 8 * * 1-5 root /bin/echo '.facebook.com' >> /etc/squid3/blockedsites.txt && /usr/sbin/squid3 -k reconfigure
00 12 * * 1-5 root /bin/sed -i '/.facebook.com/d' /etc/squid3/blockedsites.txt && /usr/sbin/squid3 -k reconfigure
30 13 * * 1-5 root /bin/echo '.facebook.com' >> /etc/squid3/blockedsites.txt && /usr/sbin/squid3 -k reconfigure
30 16 * * 1-5 root /bin/sed -i '/.facebook.com/d' /etc/squid3/blockedsites.txt && /usr/sbin/squid3 -k reconfigure
```

but each time the cron job finish running, facebook blocking/unblocking are effective only with new browser session. Those old facebook sessions are still accessible.
Are there anyway to take the rule effective immediately after the squid reconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

Please use different acl names.. you are using officehours twice to define acls, acl names should not be duplicate.

Make it officehoursAM and officehoursPM or something as you wish and specify

```
http_access deny facebook officehoursAM 
http_access deny facebook officehoursPM
```